# web scraping titles, managed to scrape links but having difficulty with file names

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: developer_tool]

How can I scrape all the names of the file for each link? I manage to scrape the links but can't seem to scrape the name of the files. For a bit more context I used beautifulsoup and find.all to scrape all the links.

Comment: <https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord_database.html> here is the url, forgot to add it with the post

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord_database.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select('a[href$=".dat"]'):
    link = a["href"]
    name = a.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip(" \\")
    print("{:<30} {}".format(link, name))
```

Prints:

```
...
coord/wb13535sm.dat            Woody Blanchard WB135/35 R/C sailplane airfoil
coord/wb140.dat                Woody Blanchard WB140/35/FB R/C sailplane airfoil
coord/whitcomb.dat             NASA/Langley Whitcomb integral supercritical airfoil
coord/ys900.dat                YS900 hyrdofoil (Shen / Eppler)
coord/ys915.dat                YS915 hydrofoil (Shen / Eppler)
coord/ys930.dat                YS930 hydrofoil (Shen / Eppler)
```